# How can I see which duplicate has been proposed, if I've already clicked "No" on the notice and the duplicate proposer has deleted their comment?

Tags: support, duplicate-questions

I recently ran into an issue, where a user voted to close my question as a duplicate and I didn't believe that it was a duplicate. I clicked "No" on the notice shown to me and submitted it, and was about to edit in an explanation as to why the question was not a duplicate.

However, the duplicate's proposer had deleted the automatic comment submitted on behalf of them when voting, so there was no apparent way for me to see the link to the proposed duplicate, so I could better explain why the question was not a duplicate and link to it in my question body.

How can I see the proposed duplicate, if I've already dismissed the automatic banner and the duplicate's proposer has deleted the automatic comment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can see the proposed duplicate by using the close or flag dialog. Click "flag"..."a duplicate" (or "close"..."Duplicate of..." if you have 250 reputation), and the proposed duplicate will be shown as the first choice in the list of potential choices.

This also works even if there are no actual close votes (i.e. only recommend closure flags, which also trigger the banner and comment) - even though the duplicate reason may not show any votes in the initial closing dialog, if you click through to the duplicate reason, you'll see it (the number next to the choice includes both close votes and recommend closure flags).

I think there should be a better way to see the duplicate target in this case, however. I liked the old behavior of the notice where the option to self-close would disappear upon making an edit, but the link would still show. Keeping the new notice in this form, but without the "question" (as to whether or not the question is a duplicate), would also better indicate that while the user indicated that it's not answered, others still believe it to be the case and that they should edit their post to make it clear.

Comment: Did you look in the timeline?

Comment: @DavidPostill Normal users can't see Close Votes tasks there if they're still pending, only moderators can. Others can only see them if they're completed.